# How do I use custom binary in my dokku host?

Tags: dokku

Part of my code requires me to run `pdftotext` directly. I'm not sure how to install it from my dokku installation, any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can install custom packages via apt using the [dokku-apt](https://github.com/dokku-community/dokku-apt) plugin. Install that plugin and add a file called `apt-packages` to the base of your code repository. This file should have the following as it's contents:

```
poppler-utils
```

The `poppler-utils` package includes `pdftotext`, so on your next deploy, this file will be picked up and the plugin will automatically install the package for you.